# Can ng-invalid parameters work similarly to a conditional ng-required?

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, validation, drupal

This is my first time asking something here so I tried to put as much information as possible to help in my predicament.

I have a question pertaining to an HTML form I'm building that uses some AngularJS which I'm learning more about as I go along.

The form itself uses some mathematics in it which I'm generating a dividend from 2 fields at a time while also factoring in a total number of people. The page itself will generate the dividend on the page itself to give the user a real-time look at their math, so there are already ng-models on most if not all fields. The catch is that the dividend itself for the fields cannot exceed 1 as I'm doing percentages from 0-100%.

Previously if the numerator was higher than the denominator, or the denominator was higher than the max amount of people I would have an explanation field that was previously be a non-required field toggle to required like so:

```
<textarea rows="4.5" cols="50" id="My_Fields_Notation__c" tabindex="11"
name="My_Fields_Notation__c" maxlength="255"
ng-required='fieldDen < fieldNum || fieldDen > numberOfPeople'
type="text"></textarea>
```

My question is if I was to remove the ng-required on this field and add a separate ng-invalid on the numerator and denominator each

(`ng-invalid='fieldDen < fieldNum'` on the numerator and `ng-invalid='fieldDen > numberofPeople'` on the denominator)

Would that cause the field to not submit if those parameters are met? (ex. if a user has Numerator: 100, Denominator: 50 and/or Number of people: 100, Denominator: 101 would the form not submit since the numbers don't meet those parameters I'm trying to set)

EDIT: If this helps to better explain my situation. I have several numerators and denominators for this form all with their own ng-model names.

The numerator cannot be higher than the denominator
The denominator cannot be higher than the number of people
If either or happens on any of the numerators and denominators, I want to block submission of the form

At the same time the form is in a drupal page and the only JS file I've been able to successfully call in was the angular file so far, so I think any additional script needs to be coded in the page itself if I need to create any controllers.

Comment: I think I have a possible solution if anyone would be able to proof my code/see if I'm missing anything<br />
`var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.check = function (){
   if($scope.firstDen) {
    $scope.demoFormData.firstDen.$setValidity(max, $scope.firstDen<=$scope.numberOfPeople);
   }
   if($scope.firstNum) {
    $scope.demoFormData.firstNum.$setValidity(max, $scope.firstNum<=$scope.firstDem);
   }

 };
});`<br /> I then put an ng-disabled set as such `ng-disabled="demoFormData.$invalid"`

Answer (score 0):

If your form submit's or doesn't submit depends on how you do the submission.

It will submit if you use:

```
<button ng-click='mySubmitFunction()'>Submit</button>
```

It will not submit if you use:

```
<button ng-click='formValid() && mySubmitFunction()'>Submit only if valid</button>
```

To check if your validation condition is met add a validation function:

```
$scope.formValid = {
    return ($scope.fieldDen < $scope.numberofPeople) && ($scope.fieldDen < $scope.fieldNum)
}
```

If you only want to validate a certain input you can also write a validation directive for this. This let's you show i.e. custom error messages if a certain condition is not met like the format, example plunkr taken from the docs: http://plnkr.co/edit/7ewLoTgWWwyeo7HAvTqU?p=preview

Comment: Okay, so for the mySubmitFunction, should I make add this to a script tag in my code?:
  `angular.module('submitForm', [])
    .controller('InvalidController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.mySubmitFunction = function() {
        if (fieldDen < fieldNum) {
   fieldNum = ng-invalid;
        }
  else if (fieldDen > numberOfPeople) {
   fieldDen = ng-invalid;
      };
    }]);`

Or would it look like something different?

Comment: given this scope, a few things: 1. could this work if there multiple numerator and denominator ng-models on a single form. 2. Since I actually am setting this up in a Drupal content manager? Could I add the scope code to a <script> tag in with the rest of the form content instead of calling in a separate js file? I've been having problems calling in other .js files. 3. Obvious question answer most likely, but I like to cover all bases, these scopes should all be in an all inclusive controller correct?

Answer (score 0):

you can add a ngPattern to the input you want to validate and then you just can use the $valid given by angularjs to validate that element.

```html
 <form name="myForm">
   <input type="text" name="userName" ng-model="user.name" ng-pattern="{string}" >
 </form>

//to test just use
{myForm.userName.$valid}
```

Comment: Would the ng-pattern work with boolean ng-models? kinda like this:
`ng-pattern = "'model1' < 'model2' || 'model2' > 'modelA' && [1-9]{1, 3}"`

Comment: i think no , the attribute value is a string that contains the regular expression (RegExp)